# How to create a closure in Kotlin which takes any type of parameter and give any type of variable as return value?

Tags: generics, kotlin, closures

I'm trying to create a closure which takes any type of object and after mutating it gives another type of object. I tried like this;

```
fun bar(fooFn: (Any?)->Any?): String {
    return fooFn(3) as String
}

val foo = { test: Int -> "Just Testing $test" }

fun main() {
    // I'm expecting this to print "Just Testing 3"
    println(bar(foo))
}
```

But this give a Type mismatch error and doesn't compile.
How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. Do you want to create a higher order function of type `(T) -> R`?

Comment: You should not use `as String` in this case. You'd run into class cast exceptions

Comment: Yes @AdamArold I'm trying to do that but additionally it can be also (T) -> T not only (T) -> R.

Comment: @tynn I'm not getting class cast exception from there but I'm getting from the bar(foo).

Comment: I just realised my comment got deleted somehow.. however what you're trying to achieve is something similar to [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), where you have type `T` in input (in this case as a receiver) and `R` in output. Obviously it will work even if `T == R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `test: Int` of `foo`:

```
val foo = { test: Int -> "Just Testing $test" }
```

`foo` requires `test` to be an `Int`. If you call `foo` with a parameter of type `Any?`, it might be null or a type like `String`. But that would not work. So if you declare it as `test: Any?`, your code would compile.

Comment: I need to define test as Int in my code, because I don't want to suppress UNCHECKED_CAST error in my closure all over the place I use this function. But this answer is still correct so I accept. Also I found an another way to achieve my goal; 
`
fun <T : Any?, R: Any?>bar(fooFn: (T)->R): String {
    return fooFn(3 as T) as String
}  
`